# Do the series have to be described by the same number of lags in a Moving Average Model to fit a VARMA model?

Tags: vector-autoregression, moving-average

Besides the other requirements for VAR, do the series have to be best described by the same number of MA terms to be included in a VARMA model?

As I understand it, the AR in VAR equals the lag of the peak of the Cross-correlation function rather than the actual AR terms the series are best described.

Comment: I would not worry about equality of the number of MA lags in univariate models when constructing a VARMA model. Also, what is the source of *the AR in VAR equals the lag of the peak of the Cross-correlation function*? (Just curious.)

Comment: Diebold made a book and code

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? I would like to look that up.

Comment: Look at his housing dataset code.

Comment: I cannot see a code section on his website. Where should I look?

Comment: https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Textbooks.html Go to the Forecasting Book's code